# Why is the catch Exception always called e

Tags: java

For example:

```
try {
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nYour number is: "+n);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You entered a value thats not valid.");
```

It seems like every program with a `catch` statement in it has the `Exception` called `e`. Is this like an unwritten rule or something?

Comment: Call it whatever you like. It's just habit and custom.

Comment: It's a personal preference generally speaking. Some people use `e`, some use `ex`, others still use the initials of each exception, so `FileNotFoundException` gets reduced to `fnfe`. There's no rule that dictates how you should name them, but the overwhelming majority of people don't do all that much with instances of exceptions beyond just logging them or wrapping and rethrowing them, so coming up with meaningful names for them isn't particularly important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same reason why camelCase is generally used in java for naming, you can use snake_case but it's not recommended and makes your code harder to read for whatever reason.

```
String helloWorld;
String hello_world;//seems a bit off doesn't it.
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of conventions. Naming things is hard. Having a common vocabulary helps understanding each other's code.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, no there is no such rule, it is just shorter like that... It is up to you and to your programming habit.